# Looking for the original quote from the film Le Brio

Tags: traduction

“When you only use complicated words for a while, you forget to say things the easy way.”

Answer (score 2):

« Quand on parle bien, on oublie de dire les choses simplement » selon http://www.lekinorama.com/Cinema/le-brio.html